# EditText that dynamically make numbers subscripted - Android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext, textview

I want to make an `EditText(and also a TextView)`, where numbers are automatically in a lower position, immediately when the number is typed by the User, so the User can make a **chemical equation** with numbers lower than the text.

I already know that you can use `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sub>2</sub>"));`

to make a specific string lower, but it is not dynamic for the User to put in numbers lower than text.

Thanks already.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Or you want to know some flow/algorithm?

Comment: @NabinKhadka I want to know how I can make my editText do this, I have no clue how to do it :P so I need some code or an idea.

Comment: Study about this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Comment: Then do something, and come back with more questions